# Problem with a JSON Object ( deep search )

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys i have a big Problem, i've been trying to solve it for days.I have an entangled JSON Object ( http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.1.1/data/de_DE/runesReforged.json ) and for example this Array with my ID's in it.

```
0: 8214 1: 8112 2: 8005 3: 8010 4: 8112 5: 8359 6: 8437 7: 9923 8: 8112 9: 8021
```

And I want the id to be searched for with the help of this array in the json Object. And after a match, the content of "icon" should be returned,
but i dont know how :( 
I tried it on so many ways, but i dont have the result that i want. The ID's are among others under `the_json_object[0].slots[0].runes[0].id`
I read that you could solve it with recursive functions but I tried and did not get the desired result.

Maybe you guys can help me :) i would be very thankful

Comment: Hi, David. Welcome to Stack Overflow. The JSON in the link is too big. Please add a minimal version of the JSON to the question itself to create a [mcve]. If that link is deleted, this question stands useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you could do something roughly as follows:

```
var ids = [8214,8112,8005,8010,8112,8359,8437,9923,8112,8021];
var results = [];

ids.map(function(id) {
    results.push({key: id, icon: ''});
});
```

Then given your object you could map through it's children as folllows:

```
the_json_object.map(function(item){
    item.slots.map(function(slot){
        slot.runes.map(function(rune){

            if(ids.indexOf(rune.id) != -1) {
                results.map(function(result){
                    if(result.key == rune.id) result.icon = rune.icon;
                });                           
            }

        });     
    });
});

var icons = [];
results.map(function(result){
  icons.push(result.icon);
});
```

logging the icons object would then provide you a string array of icons as follows:

```
["perk-images/Styles/Domination/Electrocute/Electrocute.png", "perk-images/Styles/Domination/HailOfBlades/HailOfBlades.png", "perk-images/Styles/Inspiration/Kleptomancy/Kleptomancy.png", "perk-images/Styles/Precision/PressTheAttack/PressTheAttack.png", "perk-images/Styles/Precision/FleetFootwork/FleetFootwork.png", "perk-images/Styles/Precision/Conqueror/Conqueror.png", "perk-images/Styles/Resolve/GraspOfTheUndying/GraspOfTheUndying.png", "perk-images/Styles/Sorcery/SummonAery/SummonAery.png"]
```

Hope this helps.

Matt

Comment: Wow thank you a lot it works fine for me :) But i have a question: For example, in the array, the ID exists twice, but I get it back only once, but I would like to get it back so many times according to the ID. 

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Thank you sooo much it works fine for me :) but how can i mark it as THE ANSWER i'm new here :) i need reputation or? but one last question please why is the array sorted at the end?
Would it be possible for the array to be filled as it is called?

Comment: No worries, thanks for marking it as the answer. The reason it executed like this was for efficiency, so that the JSON object did not have to be iterated for every item being searched for.

I've now updated it to work in the way you requested. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the suitable way would be to sort data. You can do this by splitting the string.
If you split the string on the basis of White spaces you can get key value pairs.
For example from string *

> 0:8214 1:8112 2:8005 3:8010 4:8112 5:8359 6:8437 7:9923 8:8112 9:8021

- `var res = str.split(" ");`
  if you split with white space it will provide you with key value pairs from which you can form a list of objects and it will be easy for you search from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an flat array with the all the needed icons, you could use something like this:

```
  let the_runes = [ 8214, 8112, 8005 /* ... */ ];
  let the_icons = [];

  for (let first_level_obj of the_json_object) {
      for (let slot_obj of first_level_obj.slots) {
          for (let rune_obj of slot_obj.runes) {
              if (the_runes.includes(rune_obj.id)) {
                  the_icons.push({
                      id: rune_obj.id,
                      icon: rune_obj.icon
                  });
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

The `the_icons`-array will hold objects with `id` and its corresponding `icon` as its properties.

Comment: thank you for the answer Jan but is not that inefficient to use so many for loops?

Comment: Yes, it's not the most efficient way. When your data-length is always similar to the json-data you provided in the url of your question, it should not a have big impact. If the data-set gets bigger the loops can get more inefficient.